# Wrong url from image_tag and paperclip in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I use Paperclip gem in my Rails app for image uploading. But in views, there are no images. The path of missing images is `http://localhost:3000/assets/`.
Here is the code:

```
<div class="advert_images">
  Фото: <br>
  <% if @advertising.image.url %>
    <%= image_tag(@advertising.image) %>    
  <% end %>
  <br>
  Розташування на карті: <br>
  <% if @advertising.map.url(:normal) %>
    <%= image_tag(@advertising.map.url(:normal)) %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

The strange thing is when a put in the code `<%= @advertising.image.url %>` that shows me the correct path of existing image (for example `/system/adverts/images/000/001/408/original/luxot.gif?1355951576`).

The model:

```
# -*- encoding : utf-8 -*-
class Advert < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :adress, :category, :city, :desc, :map_path, :name, :image_path, :map,        :image
has_attached_file :map, :styles => {:normal => "350x265", :thumb => "250x165"}
has_attached_file :image, :styles => {:normal => "350x265", :thumb => "250x165"}

  validates :name,  :length => {:in => 2..20}, :presence => true
  validates :category,                         :presence => true
  validates :city,                             :presence => true
  validates :adress,                           :presence => true


scope :by_city, lambda {|city| where("city = ?", city)}
scope :by_category, lambda {|category| where("category = ?", category)}

end
```

Comment: hm. Have you tried to enter URL in browser 0.0.0.0:3000/system/adverts/images/000/001/408/original/luxot.gif ?

Comment: And how `<%= image_tag(@advertising.map.url(:normal)) %>` is rendered to HTML?

Comment: <img alt="Assets" src="/assets/" width="250" />

Comment: What will be rendered by following code:
`<%= @advertising.map.url(:normal) %>
<%= image_tag(@advertising.map.url) %>`

Comment: In your development/production.rb set config.serve_static_assets = true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution.
I changed the default path, where paper clip stores images.

```
  has_attached_file :image,
                :url => "/assets/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
                :path =>  
                ":rails_root/app/assets/images/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
```